# Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module

Tags: arduino

Estoy compilando ejemplo con el **ESP32** con el archivo **Blynk** y no compila, no le cambié nada, solo el *pin* y ya:

```
    void setup() {
      pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    }

    void loop() {
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      delay(1000);                      
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error? ¿Cual IDE utilizas?

Comment: Fijate bien que sea un "error", no un "warning".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a colocar el Pin en una variable

```
   int pLed = 2; 

    void setup() 
   {
      pinMode(pLed, OUTPUT);
    }

    void loop() 
    {
      digitalWrite(pLed, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(pLed, LOW);
      delay(1000);                      
    }
```